# Extract rows from data frame

Tags: r

```
#Simulated data /model output
data1 <-data.frame(col1=c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), 
                col2=c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,20,22),
                col3=c(3,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33),
                col4= c(4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40))

#Lower 95% CI from real data                    
lowdata <- as.data.frame(matrix(0,1,4))
                       lowdata[,1] <-5
                       lowdata[,2] <-34
                       lowdata[,3] <-25
                       lowdata[,4] <-30

# Higher 95% CI from real data
highdata <-as.data.frame(matrix(0,1,4))
                       highdata[,1] <- 59
                       highdata[,2] <- 60
                       highdata[,3] <- 50
                       highdata[,4] <- 49
```

I am new to R programming and not sure how to do the following.

I want to basically find out which ones of the data1 rows have values (for each column) that are within the Cis defined by two the two dataframes (lowdata1 and highdata1).

I have tried this, but it takes each value and not row:

```
wmax <- which(data1[,1:4] < highdata1[,1:4])
wmin <- which(data1[,1:4] > lowdata1[,1:4])
w <- intersect(wmax, wmin)
```

How could I achieve extracting which rows in data1 basically "fit" between the CIs?

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether each element of each column is in the corresponding interval with

```
is.btwn <- 
  Map(function(x, low, high) x >= low & x <= high,
      data1, lowdata, highdata)

is.btwn
# $col1
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 
# $col2
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 
# $col3
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# 
# $col4
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

You can use `Reduce` to get rows where all columns are in the interval, but in this case there are no such rows

```
Reduce(`&`, is.btwn)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Or the rows with any column in the corresponding interval

```
Reduce(`|`, is.btwn)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

All of these results can be passed to `which` to get indices with value `TRUE`